# A word for someone who occupies a position

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a lexicalization for someone who holds a position, for example, in a company, in the army, in an organization, etc.?

> All of the relevant **___________** should be promptly contacted and updated.

*Position-holder* seems so awkward.

Comment: How about: "*All of the relevant **personnel** should be contacted.*"

Comment: You're asking for a very general word, yet your dissatisfaction with the answers below suggest you have a particular situation in mind.  Just be clear about your actual context, and you'll get a better suggestion.

Comment: Unicorns!‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: Huh? What does that mean?

Comment: Change *all of the* > *all the* > *all*.

Comment: All relevant people

Comment: You should explain exactly what office the person holds _in the question itself._ From your comment re: Kris's answer, you are looking for a synonym of "board member", which is a rather specific form of office

Answer (score 4):

*[incumbent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incumbent)*

*noun*

> **1** The holder of an office or post:
>   *the present incumbent will soon be retiring*

[EDIT]
Usage [emphasis added]:

Aron & Nightgale, ***Incumbent*** Workers' Views about Lifelong Learning, 1995, p.[7](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=mmxZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22incumbent%22&dq=%22incumbent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cJ87U8TcKsi1iQfk3oDQDQ&redir_esc=y)

> … (2) evaluate the individual labor market impacts of increased education and training among **incumbent** workers.

Sims, *Reforming (transforming?) a Public Human Resource Management Agency*, 2010, p.[234](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=dOKzEpL39U4C&dq=%22incumbent%20employee%22)

> a. If an active eligibility list for the new classification exists, the **incumbent** employee was on the eligibility list, and the **incumbent** employee met all other eligibility requirements, he or she might be appointed from the eligibility list to the reclassified position.

Smyth, *Employed but not Engaged*, 2010, p.[90](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=p-c557CmT5oC&pg=PA90&dq=%22incumbent%20employee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OaI7U-6OGciKiQfHi4G4DA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22incumbent%20employee%22&f=false)

> If the old role becomes redundant, and a new role created, then there is no absolute obligation to move the **incumbent** employee over to the new role. That said, you do have an obligation in any redundancy to consider redeployment opportunities for redundant employees, and in this case that would involve offering the new role to the **incumbent** employee.

Comment: Why do you think it's too narrow? In what sense?

Comment: Because I associate "incumbent" only with someone in high office. 
The specific context that I encountered was in a board meeting, where specific criteria were to be applied to the appropriate "position-holders"...

Comment: What makes you associate the word with 'high office' only? Have you checked the dictionary? Can you add something to enlighten me about that?

Comment: Simply because I've never heard it used in the sense of incumbent junion employees. Doesn't mean it can't be used, but I think that if you do a Google search, 95% of the hits will be about incumbent leaders of countries or large organizations...

Comment: @Ilanysong That's another meaning of *incumbent*, used in the political context. Both definitions are there in the dictionary.

Comment: @Ilanysong: *Incumbent* can certainly used for any office to which people are elected or appointed for limited terms. I personally wouldn't use it for a general or a supreme court member, for example, because these aren't limited-term positions, and I think of *incumbent* as having the implication of limited-term (exceptions made for elected officials seem to hold their positions for life).

Answer (score 2):

One word which is used is ***post-holder***.

> *noun*
>     (*formal*) a person who has a particular job or position
>
> [[Collins]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/post-holder)

It is likely to fit in the quoted sentence:

> All of the relevant post-holders should be promptly contacted and updated.

Comment: I was going to say **chair-holder**, but I think that's just a variant of **post-holder**.

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late, but you're probably looking for the word **office-bearers**.

> a person holding a position of authority in an organization

Answer (score 1):

*Office holder?*

But not every position is considered an office.  Go ahead and coin *position holder*. ;-)

I agree  with Peter's comment:

> You're asking for a very general word, yet your dissatisfaction with the answers below suggest you have a particular situation in mind. Just be clear about your actual context, and you'll get a better suggestion.

Your template is too general, and doesn't make much sense to me:

> All of the relevant **_______** should be promptly contacted and updated.

If you are talking about **people**, how would they be "**updated**"?  I can see that the positions, or information about the positions (e.g. who holds them) might be updated. But by saying "contacted" you clearly are not looking for a words such as *positions*.

In sum, if you cannot really characterize what this is about (what you are looking for) then you are likely to be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

*Functionary*

I think this might be the best option. I wonder if the word make sense in a variety of settings (e.g. government, corporate world, military, etc.)

Comment: It could be, only you know what context you're using it in. I've never seen functionary used in the corporate world, and it's not a terribly flattering word. It tends to be used to describe foreign military bureaucrats.

Answer (score 0):

In business you would say stakeholder. Instead of shareholder, which just means people who own stock in the company, stakeholder means anyone who has a stake in the endeavor, including employees, customers, relevant community members etc.

Comment: Thanks milestyle- but I don't think that's what we're looking for. A stakeholder, like you said, is anyone who has an interest in a company, a project, and so forth. Here, we're looking for someone who fills a function within an organization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just use the phrase - **current** X.

"Our current Vice-President is Tom."